# How do I update a member in a set of std::pair?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, stdset

I tried doing this:

```
std::set< pair<int, int> > mySet;

// fill the set with something

mySet.find( make_pair(someValueX, someValueY) )->first = newX;
```

But I get the following error on compilation:

```
error: assignment of member 'std::pair<int, int>::first' in read-only object|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===||
```

Comment: You can't, you need to remove the pair and insert the new one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `std::pair`, it's a limitation imposed by `std::set`.

Answer (score 8):

Members of `std::set` are `const`, because changing them could make their ordering invalid. You would have to erase the pair and re-insert it after it was changed.

Comment: Oh, now I understand... This was bugging me for some time and had no idea why it didn't work. Thanks!